# Chrome Enterprise extensions displaying "Not allowed" in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, enterprise, chromebook

we are writing a chrome extension that uses the enterprise apis namely the following calls:

```
let hardwareInfo = 

  await chrome.enterprise.hardwarePlatform.getHardwarePlatformInfo(); 

payload["manufacturer"] = hardwareInfo.manufacturer ?? null; 

payload["model"] = hardwareInfo.model ?? null; 



 let serialNoInfo = 

    await chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDeviceSerialNumber(); 

  payload["serial_no"] = serialNoInfo.serialNumber ?? null;
```

It IS working for the following calls for network details:

```
chrome.enterprise.networkingAttributes.getNetworkDetails((info) => { 

  payload["mac_address"] = info.macAddress ?? null;
```

We are finding that when deployed in a enterprise we are still getting "not allowed" errors in the console when trying to call those APIs.

We are unable to get this data back for some reason and not sure where to go from here.  We are told the policies are set up correctly from Google Support on the enterprise side of things when deploying.

We were able to get manufacturer and model when working locally on our macbook.

Anyone see this or can offer some help, we are failing to see how this isn't the policies and how they are set up in the enterprise?

Answer (score 3):

May be my answer will help you with "chrome.enterprise.hardwarePlatform". You have to enable "EnterpriseHardwarePlatformAPIEnabled" chrome enterprise policy (https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=EnterpriseHardwarePlatformAPIEnabled). Please note that in my case I didn't add Win registry key and it works ok without it.

I have to say that this is not documented here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/enterprise_hardwarePlatform/ so developer has no clue why exactly this very API doesn't work (it also cannot be googled).

---

**Update:**

I also asked the question about other APIs here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1358431#c2

And got the next answer:

> It seems the documentation site is not doing a good job of processing and  displaying the platform availability for these particular APIs, as a lot of  **them are explicitly restricted to chromeos + lacros** in the related  permission feature files[1]. **There's no way around those platform  restrictions** sorry, but I'll open a documentation bug for the availability not being listed accurately on the doc site.

So the final resolution is - **chrome.enterprise.hardwarePlatform** can be enabled, **chrome.enterprise.hardwarePlatform** and **chrome.enterprise.networkingAttributes** cannot be enabled except for the Chromeos and Lacros.

Best,
Nick

Comment: Added update for my answer.